# Mongomapper - unit testing with shoulda on rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, shoulda, mongomapper

I'm trying to implement shoulda unit tests on a rails 2.3.5 app using mongomapper.

So far I've:

1. Configured a rails app that uses mongomapper (the app works)
2. Added shoulda to my gems, and installed it with `rake gems:install`
3. Added `config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource` ] to `config/environment.rb` so `ActiveRecord` isn't used.

My models look like this:

```
class Account
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String, :required => true
  key :description, String
  key :company_id, ObjectId
  key :_type, String

  belongs_to :company
  many :operations

end
```

My test for that model is this one:

```
class AccountTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  should_belong_to :company
  should_have_many :operations

  should_validate_presence_of :name

end
```

It fails on the first `should_belong_to`:

```
./test/unit/account_test.rb:3: undefined method `should_belong_to' for AccountTest:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Should I try something different from shoulda?

I must point out that this is the first time I try to use shoulda, and I'm pretty new to testing itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying shoulda more profoundly, I realized what was wrong.

Shoulda's macros (`should_belong_to`, `should_have_many`, `should_validate_presence_of`) are only available for ActiveRecord - after all they are defined on [Shoulda::ActiveRecord::Macros](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/thoughtbot/shoulda/Shoulda/ActiveRecord/Macros.html).

If I were to use those, I would have to implement macros for Shoulda::MongoMapper::Macros. I'm not sure it is worth it.

I hope this helps anyone finding this post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guys at thoughtbot will move these to Shoulda::ActiveModel::Macros sooner or later.

Comment: Nevermind. I realized that that kind of tests (should_belong_to etc) aren't really the important things to test. See http://www.lmcavalle.com/2009/03/18/structure-based-testing.html